# How to provide feedback of TestFlight iOS beta apps?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight, feedback, beta-testing

The only Apple's documentation regarding TestFlight I found is this in [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH35-SW2), and I found nothing regarding reporting crashes or/and getting another feedback from beta-testers... Where can I find it? What kind of feedback can I get by using TestFlight and how? I also read [here](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) that there should be a sort of "Provide Feedback" button that I don't find... does it no longer exist in current TestFlight?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Crashes can be found in the Organiser from Xcode -> Windows -> Organiser. The crashes are in the second tab (right beside "Archives").

User feedback is submitted in TestFlight. When you click into the app detail, there's a large horizontal button saying "Send Feedback".

Comment: Thank you. Regarding the "Send Feedback" button... I only see Description and Information of the app, "Developer Website", "Notifications" and "Stop testing"... am I missing to enable something somewhere?

Comment: No, the user provides feedback, not you :p

Comment: Sure :D, I was checking the TestFlight app of one of my external tester's device

Answer (score 0):

You already got answer regarding crashes, my reply is about Feedback in TestFlight.

This seems to be old question but people keep asking it today. 
I also had it and contacted Apple Developer support about it and they asked me the following:

1) Do You have Feedback e-mail configured in Testflight?

I had it configured of course so they only answered demanding screenshots, app ids, e-mails , e t.c. and other proof that I am not kidding. Then they asked me second question which I think sheds light:

2) Does Your tester have Apple Mail configured?

"... the tester should have Apple Mail configured on the device from which he can send an email. (It does not mean that the email address should be an Apple ID, but it should be configured with Apple Mail)."

They mean, Apple MAIL app that comes with iOS. That's how TestFlight feedback works - by fetching sender's e-mail from Apple Mail app when tester taps "feedback" button. No configured Mail app - no Feedback button.